# Problema al pasar datos entre activity Android Studio

Tags: java, android-studio, activity

Me surgió un problema, pongo un ejemplo para que se entienda. Tengo un Activity de login basico (nombre y apellido, es para utilizarlos luego) ingreso los campos y los envío a través de un intent a mi MainActivity, los datos llegan muy bien y los puedo usar, pero el problema es que cuando voy desde mi MainActivity a un SecondActivity y posteriormente regreso a mi MainActivity esos datos que pase desde el ActivityLogin los perdí, y me quedan como valores null, alguien sabe porque pasa eso?

Comment: ¿Cuál es el error que figura en el `LogCat`? Deberías poner código, ¿Hay un error? ¿Puedes ser más detallado?

Comment: Agrega más información a tu pregunta, que código estas usando?

Comment: Creo que el cambio que has realizado en el título no es correcto, @Elenasys. Su problema se da cuando sale de esa activity y vuelve, no al recibir los datos de otra activity

Comment: El usuario pregunta que tiene problemas al enviar los datos, de una a otra Activity,  el usuario pregunta "enviar", no "mantener" como lo modificaste, lo que no es correcto es responder cuando el usuario no agrega información necesaria, si modificaste el titulo para que tu respuesta se apegara a él estas probablemente modicando la idea que plasma en su pregunta, primero hay que preguntar al OP que agregué más información de otra forma estas contribuyendo a que se tengan preguntas de baja calidad en el sitio.

Answer (score 1):

Bienvenido al [ciclo de vida de un activity](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle?hl=es#alc). Para evitar que eso suceda hay varias opciones:

1. Guardar los valores en una DB / [SharedPreferences](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared-preferences)
2. Utilizar un patrón MVVM donde la vista pide sus datos siempre al [ViewModel](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/lifecycle/ViewModel?hl=es), el cual tiene la capacidad de mantener los datos aun cuando la activity se ha pausado/parado.
3. El más fácil y útil para solo un par de valores: Utilizar el bundle savedInstanceState. ¿Nunca te has preguntado por qué cuando inicias un activity siempre tienes un savedInstanceState? Precisamente para poder mantener variables! Precisamente este método te voy a explicar:

Primero para persistir tus variables necesitarás sobreescribir el método onSaveInstanceState, podrás encontrarlo (si usas Android Studio) pulsando ctrl + O:

```
@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    //Guardamos el nombre y el apellido en el "outState"
    outState.putString("nombre", variableConElNombre);
    outState.putString("apellido", variableConElApellido);
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
}
```

Hasta ahí bien, pero eso solo es la mitad del trabajo! Ahora nos toca recoger los datos! Para ello en el método onCreate de la activity deberemos comprobar si savedInstanceState está a null (Es decir, es la primera vez que se crea la activity) o si tiene contenido (Es decir, la activity se está restaurando):

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //Si no es null, simplemente recogemos nuestras variables!
    if (savedInstanceState != null) { 
        String nombre = savedInstanceState.getString("nombre");
        String apellido = savedInstanceState.getString("apellido");
        Toast.makeText(this, "Nombre:" + nombre + " - Apellido: " + apellido, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

Si pretendes guardar varias variables, te recomiendo que uses las SharedPreferences y si vas a tener una aplicación un poco grande, lo mejor sería usar una base de datos [sqLite](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/sqlite?hl=es-419) y mejor aun con un gestor de persistencia como [Room](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room?hl=es-419) que hace casi todo el trabajo por ti. Además, tanto las SharedPreferences como la base de datos te darán persistencia de los datos al cerrar la aplicación, mientras que el uso del bundle savedInstanceState se limita a la vida de la aplicación.